# Adding background when outputting PDF in Processing 4 JAVA

Tags: java, pdf, plot, processing

With Processing 4, I can save my data in PDF format. But it doesn't happen when I try to add an image behind the PDF output. I have to use beginRecord() function because I need to record data continuously.

```
public void setup() 
{  
  GPointsArray pointsECG = new GPointsArray(nPoints1);
 
  size(1024, 600, JAVA2D);
  backgroundImage = loadImage(ecgeniyi.png);
  heightHeader=100;
  println("Height:"+height);

  totalPlotsHeight=height-heightHeader;
  
  makeGUI();
  surface.setTitle("Healthy Race");
  PImage icon = loadImage("hr.png");
  surface.setIcon(icon);
  
  plot1 = new GPlot(this);
  plot1.setPos(20,200);
  plot1.setDim(width-40, (totalPlotsHeight/3)-10);
  plot1.setBgColor(0);
  plot1.setBoxBgColor(0);
  plot1.setLineColor(color(255, 255, 255));
  plot1.setLineWidth(1);
  plot1.setMar(0,0,0,0);

  for (int i = 0; i < nPoints1; i++) 
  {
 
    pointsECG.add(i,0);

  }
  
  plot1.setPoints(pointsECG);

  for (int i=0; i<windowSize; i++) 
  {

    ch1Data[i] = 0;
    ch2Data[i] = 0;
    
  }

}


public void draw() 
{
  background(255);
 // background(19,75,102);

  GPointsArray pointsPlot1 = new GPointsArray(nPoints1);


  if (startPlot)                             // If the condition is true, then the plotting is done
  {
    for(int i=0; i<nPoints1;i++)
    {    
      pointsPlot1.add(i,ch1Data[i]);
    }
  } 
  else                                     // Default value is set
  {
  }

  plot1.setPoints(pointsPlot1);

  
  plot1.beginDraw();
  plot1.drawBackground();
  plot1.drawLines();
  plot1.endDraw();

if(c == true){
if(f == true){
  pdf.nextPage();
  f = false;
}}

  
}

public void RecordData()
{
      c = true;

  pdf = (PGraphicsPDF)beginRecord(PDF, "Lines.pdf");
  pdf.beginDraw();
  pdf.background(255);
  pdf.image(backgroundImage, 0, 0, pdf.width, pdf.height); 
  pdf.endDraw();

  pdf.dispose();
}


public void EndRecord()
{
    c = false;

  endRecord();
}
```

Here RecordData(); I want to see an image in the background while drawing PDF lines in the function.